# Parsing &amp; to & in json in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, ipad

I have following json response.. here i displayed only few lines of it.
How can I replace `"&amp;"` with `&` and store in an array.
Thanks in advance.

```
[
    {
        "cat_id": "1",
        "cat_name": "Dining &amp; Nightlife",
        "0": {
            "subcat_id": "2",
            "subcat_name": "Restaurants"
        },
        "1": {
            "subcat_id": "3",
            "subcat_name": "Bar &amp;  Club"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for how to do this?

Comment: Yes I tried it.. But i find ways for only xmlparser. not for json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     NSString *sting=[[NSString alloc]init];
     sting=[[request responseString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
      NSDictionary *resDict =[parser objectWithString:sting error:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON data isn't properly encoded. In addition to the JSON format, all the strings seem to be HTML encoded. This is a double encoding, which is completely unnecessary.

I strongly recommend you fix this at the source, i.e. on the server. Then you have proper JSON data that can be used without problems by many different clients.

If you cannot fix it on the server, then you have to decode each string attribute in the JSON response. Before you do that, you better investigate if only ampersands are affected (unlikely) or other special characters (such as < > ä ô) as well. Then you can add this to your question and we will likely be able to help you.

**Update**:
I don't quite understand what classes you're using to keep the parsed JSON data in memory. (You mention *arrays*.) But to fix the double encoded ampersands, use the following code on each string:

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"&amp;" withString: @"&"];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have only ampersands special character in my json response.. Any way to replace or convert it to `&` ?

Comment: So you don't want to fix the problem at the source then?

Comment: I cant fix this problem at source because i cant access it. i have no any privileged to access it

Comment: See my update. You probably need to give more details about what data structures you're using.

Comment: I doubt that "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:" occurs very often in his strings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I should have a better look at my edits before I post them. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

U have to do in take array. and using for loop u can replace &amp to & and that string add in array. and make new araay...